# Issue with portion size of valves

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

I am having an issue with setting the portion size of a valve during run time. It appears to always take the values placed in the 'Properties' input boxes as its first/initial portion size. I want to have this value read in from a database during start up (ie. In Main > On Start up).

**Attempt 1**

If I assign the value that I read in from the database to a variable "parcel_size" and I place the variable name "parcel_size" in the PortionSize input, it tells be that the PortionSize cannot be zero. I assume that means it is trying to assign the value before I read it in from the database. If I give the varaible "parcel_size" a default value, it just takes that value as the first Portion Size.

**Attempt 2**

I also tried putting in a numerical value in the PortionSize input and then assigning a value during Main > On Start up using:

```
valve.set_portionSize(parcel_size, TON);
```

While this successfully assigns the subsequent portion sizes, it still takes the initial numerical value as the initial PortionSize.

I thought it may be possible bypass this issue by setting a very small value as the initial portion size - however it does not work for me as my action is also dependent on the "parcel_size":

```
valve2.dispense(parcel_size, TON);
```

So what would happen is that it will trigger dispensing the 'parcel_size' amount but when portion_size passed on valve is small. I need these to be the same amount.

**Attempt 3**

I then tried un-checking the "Recurrent action on portion" box first and then putting the following code in Main > Startup:

```
valve.set_portionSize(parcel_size, TON);
valve.actionOnPortion = true;
```

However this gives me an error of "Volume and mass parameters are incompatible"

Changing the code using cubic meter does not help:

```
valve.set_portionSize(parcel_size, CUBIC_METER);
valve.actionOnPortion = true;
```

**Is there a way around this?**

Can anyone suggest a way around this?

Sorry for the long post, but hope that it has explained my problem properly.

Comment: Can you provide some more details about where the value is that you are trying to chamge?

Comment: Hi. The main value that I'm trying to assign through the database is the PortionSize parameter of a Valve. So in the Valve Property panel, under Action (when the 'Recurrent action on portion' is checked). Is that what you mean?

Comment: See my updated answer with code of getting value from DB it works as expected - Else please paste your code for reading from DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set this from the DB you need to have code like the following for the value

[image]

I tested this and it worked.

Since the parameter is a static parameter - which you can see when you hover the little icon next to the parameter

[image]

This means that this value is evaluated once, during creation and never again.

If you want to change during runtime you will need to call `valve.set_portionSize(value)` if you want to change the value during model execution.

See below

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response Jaco-Ben. However, essentially I would like to bypass that initial evaluation of the static value (the value of 10 in your example).

Comment: I misunderstood your question - see updated answer

Comment: Thank you Jaco-Ben. Reading the value directly from the database in the portion size input worked.